# Pagination in Zend

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to create pagination.so I create a *'pagination.phtml*' and stored it in **'views/scripts/**' 
and add the given line in my *index.phtml* '**$this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'pagination.phtml');.**

pagination.phtml code is here

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount): ?> 
<div class="paginationControl"> 
 <!-- Previous page link --> 
<?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?> 
 <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->previous)); ?>"> 
 Previous 
  </a> <span class="bar"> | </span> 
  <?php else: ?> 
  <span class="disabled"> Previous</span> <span class="bar"> | </span>
```

pagesInRange as $page): ?> 
  current): ?> 
    url(array('page' => $page)); ?>"> 
         
      |  
   
      |  
   
 
 
next)): ?> 
  url(array('page' => $this->next)); ?>"> 
    Next 
   
 
  Next

My records contain 60 items,and records per page set into 10
But only first 10 items is displayed,don't display next - previous links.How solve it?? .
Expecting responses..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294429/pagination-in-zend) . Maybe it will give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print "$this->paginator" and check how much records you are getting.