# Pagination with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

I am currently trying to paginate information returned from my database.

I am currently using Zend Version 1.12 and very new to Zend and MVC. Consequently I would appreciate any advice on better layout of my code, to conform with best practices as well as a point in the right direction as to what I am missing to make my pagination code work

So far I have looked at several tutorials:
[This](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/exploring-zend-paginator/), [This](http://zendgeek.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/zend-pagination-example.html), [This](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/perm.php?a=Zend-Framework-MySQL-DB-Pagination-Tutorial), [and This](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html) and viewed a couple of stackoverflow questions including [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294429/pagination-in-zend). But i must be missing something as I cannot get it to work.

I have managed to limit the set of results that are being displayed to a number of my choice (30) and I have managed to display the pagination controls.

Unfortunately my pagination controls do not work.

PROBLEM

when I click "next" the address bar will go from
site/model/controller to site/model/controller/page/2, but the display does not change.

When I click Last the address bar will go from

site/model/controller/page/2 to site/model/controller/page/29 (which are the number of pages I would expect there to be once paginated). The display does not change.

I cannot click previous (even if i am on page 29) as it is not an active link (it is disabled in the HTML code).

My code is as follows:

Model

```
public function readAll()
{
    $tableData = new Application_Model_DbTable_Bins();
    $table = $tableData->fetchAll();

    if (!empty($table)) {
        return $table;
    } else {
        return 'There is no information held within this table';
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function readallAction($items = 10, $page = 1)
{
    $readAll = new Application_Model_Bins();

    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($readAll->readAll());
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($items);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    if ( empty ( $page ) ) { $page = 1; }
    $this->view->readall = $paginator;
}
```

View

```
<div id="view-content">
<form method='post' id="bins" name="myform">
    <table border="1">
        <th>BIN</th>
        <th>COMP_DIV</th>
        <th>STY_RET_TYPE</th>
        <th>STY_PDT_TYPE</th>
        <th>PRICE_POINT</th>
        <th>STORAGE_TYPE</th>

        <?php echo $this->partialLoop('partials/bins.phtml', $this->readall); ?>

        <td><input type=checkbox value="Check All" onClick="this.value=check(this.form.list)" /></td>
    </table>

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='move' />
</form>            
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->readall, 'Sliding', 'pagination_controls.phtml'); ?>
```

pagination Controls

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount): ?>

<!--    first Page Link-->
<?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->first)); ?>">First</a> |
<?php else: ?>
<span class="disabled">First</span> |
<?php endif; ?>

<!--    previous Pagelink-->
<?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->previous)); ?>">&lt; Previous</a> |
<?php else: ?>
<span class="disabled">&lt; Previous</span> |
<?php endif; ?>

<!--    next Page link-->
<?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->next)); ?>">Next &gt;</a> |
<?php else: ?>
<span class="disabled">Next &gt;</span> |
<?php endif; ?>

<!--    Last page link-->
<?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->last)); ?>">Last</a>
<?php else: ?>
<span class="disabled">Last</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public function readallAction(){
    $items = 10;
    $readAll = new Application_Model_Bins();
    $page = $this->_request->getParam('page',1);
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($readAll->readAll());
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($items);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    $this->view->readall = $paginator;
}
```

I recommend you use Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect to increase performance.

*I speak English not well*

---

*Update...*

Controller:

```
public function readallAction()
{
    $page = $this->_request->getParam('page',1); //get curent page param, default 1 if param not available.
    $model = new Application_Model_Bins(); // get Model
    $data = $model->_readAll(); // call Method
    $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($data); //adapter
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter); // setup Pagination
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10); // Items perpage, in this example is 10
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page); // current page
    $this->view->readall = $paginator;
}
```

Model:

```
public function _readAll(){
    $select = $this->getDefaultAdapter()->select();
    $select->from('ebook','*');
    return $select; //return sql query, do NOT return fetch data. this query is: select * from ebook
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It now works. This zend stuff is very frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect, but I cant seem to get that to work. Also how would I display the page numbers available and limit that display only 10 for example i.e. google style?

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting the parameters to be supplied to the controller method as function arguments, but it doesn't work like this. Params are added to the request object and you access them from there. Try this:

```
public function readallAction()
{
    $items = 10;
    $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page', 1);

    $readAll = new Application_Model_Bins();

    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($readAll->readAll());
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($items);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

    $this->view->readall = $paginator;
}
```

In the above I'm accessing the page param from the request object (using 1 as the default). Items I've hardcoded to 10 as that doesn't seem to be a URL parameter in the example you gave.

You asked for code feedback. One issue with your approach is that you're passing all of your data to the paginator, which will work, but isn't very efficient. Imagine if the table had a million rows - ZF is having to select all of them just to return the first 10. You might want to look into using the DB Select paginator instead, see: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html. These allow you to supply a DB select instead, which ZF can then manipulate so only the relevant 10 results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$page = $this->_getParam('page',1);
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
$this->view->paginator = $paginator
```